# Find Unique Counts By Two Groups

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply, plyr

This is a two part problem:

First, I have a set of users that are processing requests.

```
User    Voucher Number  System Entry Date   Queue Entry Date    Queue Exit Date
user1   100004  8/11/2016 10:40 8/11/2016 10:40 8/11/2016 14:48
user2   100004  8/11/2016 10:40 8/11/2016 14:48 8/12/2016 16:11
user1   100004  8/11/2016 10:40 8/12/2016 16:11 8/18/2016 16:09
user3   100004  8/11/2016 10:40 8/18/2016 16:09 8/18/2016 16:11
user1   100004  8/11/2016 10:40 8/18/2016 16:11 10/12/2016 10:07
user2   100004  8/11/2016 10:40 10/12/2016 10:07    10/13/2016 13:34
user3   100004  8/11/2016 10:40 10/13/2016 14:57    10/13/2016 14:57
user4   1030003 8/18/2016 9:45  8/22/2016 16:02 8/24/2016 11:41
user2   1030003 8/18/2016 9:45  8/24/2016 11:41 8/29/2016 18:40
user1   1030003 8/18/2016 9:45  8/29/2016 18:40 8/29/2016 18:54
user1   1030003 8/18/2016 9:45  8/29/2016 18:54 8/29/2016 18:54
```

Ultimately I need to quantify how many requests are processing each day **by the `Queue Entry Date`**. The issue is that sometimes requests are closed out by a user and reopened by the same user. As seen in the last two rows.

**If the `"user"` and `"Queue Entry Date"` is the same as the previous line then the second instance would be removed.**

I developed a for loop that checks for this but I have two problems:

(1)The loop is extremely slow and (2) say I had a voucher that was open and closed 3 or more times by the same user sequentially, I'm not entirely sure how program would handle this.

Ultimately I would need the table to look like this:

The voucher count would be the number of vouchers processed based of 'Queue Entry Date'

```
User    date    voucher count
user1   8/11/2016   3
user2   8/11/2016   2
user3   8/11/2016   2
user4   8/11/2016   0
user1   8/12/2016   1
user2   8/12/2016   1
user3   8/12/2016   0
user4   8/12/2016   1




df <- structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("    user1", "    user2", "    user3", 
"    user4"), class = "factor"), Voucher.Number = c(100004L, 
100004L, 100004L, 100004L, 100004L, 100004L, 100004L, 1030003L, 
1030003L, 1030003L, 1030003L), System.Entry.Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("8/11/2016 10:40", 
"8/18/2016 9:45"), class = "factor"), Queue.Entry.Date = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("10/12/2016 10:07", 
"10/13/2016 14:57", "8/11/2016 10:40", "8/11/2016 14:48", "8/12/2016 16:11", 
"8/18/2016 16:09", "8/18/2016 16:11", "8/22/2016 16:02", "8/24/2016 11:41", 
"8/29/2016 18:40", "8/29/2016 18:54"), class = "factor"), Queue.Exit.Date = structure(c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("10/12/2016 10:07", 
"10/13/2016 13:34", "10/13/2016 14:57", "8/11/2016 14:48", "8/12/2016 16:11", 
"8/18/2016 16:09", "8/18/2016 16:11", "8/24/2016 11:41", "8/29/2016 18:40", 
"8/29/2016 18:54"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("User", "Voucher.Number", 
"System.Entry.Date", "Queue.Entry.Date", "Queue.Exit.Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

This is the loop I used for filtering:

```
counter = 0
filtDf = data.frame()
for (elem in 1:nrow(df)){

  if (counter >0){
    curElementId <- df[counter,c(4,12)]
    prev <- df[elem,c(4,12)]
    if (curElementId[1,1] == prev[1,1] & curElementId[1,2] == prev[1,2]){
      filtDf <- rbind(filtDf,df[elem,])
    }
    else{
      filtDf <- rbind(filtDf,df[elem,])
    }
  }
  counter = counter + 1
}
```

Then used the following to create the frequency table:

```
filtDf$date<- as.POSIXct(filtDf$Queue.Exit.Date,format="%d/%d/%Y %H:%M")
filtDf$date <- as.character( round(filtDf$date , "day" ) )

dd <- ddply( filtDf , .(Queue.Entry.Date,User) , summarise , Count = length(User) )
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the numbers in the desired result come from, but I suspect it's something like `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('Date')), funs(as.Date(as.character(.), format = '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>% count(User, Queue.Entry.Date)`

Comment: your output is confusing? where did record of `user4` vanish?

Comment: @joel.wilson yes that has been updated

Comment: could you explain the date and count column you have in the o/p? which date is it? I think if you could help explain the 3 columns of date then I could understand it better. Thanks

Comment: First steps: note that R has date and datetime formats and use them before posting datetimes as strings or factors (unless that's the issue you're primarily confused about ... in which case this question should be much shorter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. First, it is converting all of the date columns to actual datetime objects using `mdy_hm` from `lubrdidate` (I agree with @Frank's comment above), then sorting by the entry datetime to ensure it is in order. Next, it is using `lag` to check whether or not a row matches the preceding row for both the user and the date of the entry. Note that it will give `NA` for the first entry, and we need to make sure not to exclude that one, so I am using `replace_na` from `tidyr` to switch the first one to `FALSE`. Then, keep only the ones not caught in your filter, and `count` by date.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(System.Entry.Date, Queue.Entry.Date, Queue.Exit.Date)
            , mdy_hm) %>%
  mutate(toFilt = (User == lag(User) &
                     as.Date(Queue.Entry.Date) == lag(as.Date(Queue.Entry.Date)) ) ) %>%
  replace_na(replace = list(toFilt = FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!toFilt) %>%
  count(User, Date = as.Date(Queue.Entry.Date))
```

Returns:

```
        User       Date     n
      <fctr>     <date> <int>
1      user1 2016-08-11     1
2      user1 2016-08-12     1
3      user1 2016-08-18     1
4      user1 2016-08-29     1
5      user2 2016-08-11     1
6      user2 2016-08-24     1
7      user2 2016-10-12     1
8      user3 2016-08-18     1
9      user3 2016-10-13     1
10     user4 2016-08-22     1
```

Note that this does *not* match your sample output, but your sample output does not match the data you posted. So, I am not sure what happened there. If you want to get the 0 classes back, you can use `complete`:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(System.Entry.Date, Queue.Entry.Date, Queue.Exit.Date)
            , mdy_hm) %>%
  arrange(Queue.Entry.Date) %>%
  mutate(toFilt = (User == lag(User) &
                     as.Date(Queue.Entry.Date) == lag(as.Date(Queue.Entry.Date)) ) ) %>%
  replace_na(replace = list(toFilt = FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!toFilt) %>%
  count(User, Date = as.Date(Queue.Entry.Date)) %>%
  complete(User, Date = full_seq(Date, 1), fill = list(n = 0))
```

If you don't want all of the dates in your range included, just use `Date` instead of the `full_seq` function.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. Could you tell me how the "." in (funs(mdy_hm(.)) works?

Comment: The `.` stands in for the column of interest (as separated by any grouping variables). In looking at the help for you, I was reminded that `mutate_each` was being deprecated, so will update to use `mutate_at` instead. `?arrange` will show you the function `desc` to sort descending (the default is ascending), though `-` generally works as well, though that does not appear to be documented and so should likely be avoided.

Comment: the newer version doesn't seem to work. It returns "Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function""

Comment: Does `df` have your actual data, or is it the native function `df` again because you didn't load your data into `df` yet?